# Only the creator user can manage AWS kubernetes cluster (EKS) from kubectl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have two clusters, named:

1. MyCluster (created by me)
2. OtherCluster (not created by me)

Where "me" is my own AWS IAM user.

I am able to manage the cluster I created, using kubectl:

```
>>> aws eks update-kubeconfig --name MyCluster –profile MyUser
>>> kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   172.20.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   59d
```

But, I cannot manage the “OtherCluster” cluster (that was not created by me):

```
>>> aws eks update-kubeconfig --name OtherCluster --profile MyUser
>>> kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "svc"
```

After reading the feedback of some people experiencing the same issue in this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues/157), I tried doing this under the context of the user who originally created the "OtherCluster".

I accomplished this by editing “~/.kube/config”, adding a “AWS_PROFILE” value at “users.user.env”. The profile represents the user who created the cluster.

~/.kube/config:

```
…
users
- name: OtherCluster
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - OtherCluster
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: OTHER_USER_PROFILE
…
```

This worked:

```
# ~/.kube/config is currently pointing to OtherCluster

>>> kubectl get svc 
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   172.20.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   1d
```

It is obviously not ideal for me to impersonate another person when I am managing the cluster. I would prefer to grant my own user access to manage the cluster via kubectl.
Is there any way I can grant permission to manage the cluster to a user other than the original creator? This seems overly restrictive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an Amazon EKS cluster is created, the IAM entity (user or role) that creates the cluster is added to the Kubernetes RBAC authorization table as the administrator. **Initially**, only that IAM user can make calls to the Kubernetes API server using kubectl.

To grant additional AWS users the ability to interact with your cluster, you must edit the `aws-auth` ConfigMap within Kubernetes, adding a new `mapUsers` entry for your ConfigMap. [This EKS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) covers all the process.

> To add an IAM user: add the user details to the mapUsers section of
>   the ConfigMap, under data. Add this section if it does not already
>   exist in the file. Each entry supports the following parameters:
>
> - userarn: The ARN of the IAM user to add.
> - username: The user name within Kubernetes to map to the IAM user. By    default, the user name is the ARN of the IAM user.
> - groups: A list of groups within Kubernetes to which the user is    mapped to. For more information, see Default Roles and Role Bindings
>     in the Kubernetes documentation.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::555555555555:role/devel-worker-nodes-NodeInstanceRole-74RF4UBDUKL6
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::555555555555:user/my-new-admin-user
      username: my-new-admin-user
      groups:
        - system:masters
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Did not work, still get authN error `Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "" cannot list services in the namespace "default"` -- I also get this error after adding clusterrolebinding, per those instructions: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding <USER>-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=<USER>`

Comment: @JamesWierzba you do not need to create any `clusterrolebinding` on your cluster (you can grant the default `system:masters` group to your new admin). The steps are: 1-Make sure that you have your own IAM user (no roles are needed). 2-Configure your _kubeconfig_ file to use the `aws-iam-authenticator` and your `AWS_PROFILE`. 3-Add your IAM user to the `mapUsers` in the `aws-auth` ConfigMap.

Answer (score 1):

Re-configuring kubectl for EKS, using the AWS auth profile for the new user, seemed to do the trick.

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name ${CLUSTER_NAME} --profile ${OTHER_USER}
```

Where `${OTHER_USER}` is the new user I am trying to grant access to the EKS cluster, and who is not the user that originally created the cluter.

I can't explain why this step worked for me now, but did not work for me earlier when I posted this question. But hopefully this helps someone else.